# How to design the base-derived class when there is a static property in base and that needs to be hidden

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class as below

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static int someValue;

    public void Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue()
    {
        // Complex large method using 'someValue'
    }
}
```

Now I need two derived classes. `ClassA:SomeClass` and `ClassB:SomeClass`.

For both of these derived classes, `Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue()` logic remains the same. But `ClassA` will have its 'someValue' and `ClassB` will have its own some other value and they are static.

How can I design the classes?

Comment: Does the value *have* to be static for any reason? Or do you just assume it should? Apart from this you shouldn´t expose a field publicily, instead you may use a public property.

Comment: This code is already there and I want to make very less changes as much as possible. It is a  public static value

Comment: If `someValue`is a public static value and you cannot change `Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue`, then there is nothing you can do, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply Template Method pattern to Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue. For this create virtual property someValueProp in SomeClass and use someValue as backing field for it. Then override this property in ClassB to use another backing field.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static int someValue;

    public virtual int someValueProp
    {
        get { return someValue; }
        set { someValue = value; }
    }

    public void Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue()
    {
        // Complex large method using 'someValueProp'
    }
}

public class ClassB : SomeClass
{
    public static int anotherValue;

    public override int someValueProp
    {
        get { return anotherValue; }
        set { anotherValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The value should still be named as someValue in derived class, not another value

Comment: If you want derived ClassB to have different value in static field then it's not possible. You can hide someValue and anotherValue from client code and use someValueProp where you planned to use someValue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way would be to implement a virtual method retrieving the static value. Call that method from `Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue()` and override it in subclasses retrieving their static values.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static int someValue;

    public virtual int GetValue() => someValue;

    public Some_Logic_That_Uses_somevalue()
    {
        // Complex large method getting 'someValue' through GetValue()
    }
}

public class ClassA : SomeClass
{
    public static int someValueForA;

    public override int GetValue() => someValueForA;
}

public class ClassB : SomeClass
{
    public static int someValueForB;

    public override int GetValue() => someValueForB;
}
```

}

Comment: Can u show the design ,both derived and base classes please